# Issue when setting cookies of WKWebView by copying cookies from HTTPCookieStorage to WKWebsiteDataStore

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, webkit, wkwebview

I want to show a website in a WKWebView in my iOS app for which I need to set specific http cookies for the user's session. The cookies are already stored in the shared HttpCookieStorage of the app.

At the moment, I try to copy them from there to the WKWebsiteDataStore of the web view before loading the website with the following code:

```
class ViewerViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var webView: WKWebView!

    // MARK: - Life Cycle
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addCookiesToWebView {
            print("Load website")
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyWebsite", withExtension: "html"), let html = try? String(contentsOf: url) {
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: url)
            }
        }   
    }

    // MARK: - Functions
    func addCookiesToWebView(completionHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        let sharedCookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!
        let webViewCookieStore = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore
        var count = 0
        sharedCookies.forEach { cookie in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                webViewCookieStore.setCookie(cookie) {
                    count += 1
                    print("Added cookie \(cookie.name)")
                    if count == sharedCookies.count {
                        completionHandler()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what is incomprehensible for me, is that this sometimes works and the user is authenticated in his user session, but sometimes it doesn't.

It seems like there might be a race condition that leads to the web view loading the website before all the cookies have been copied? When I researched this problem I noticed that other people have problems with cookies in WKWebView as well, but I didn't find any solution so far that actually solves my issue.

Is there a bug in my code or is there a better approach for copying multiple cookies from HttpCookieStorage to a WKWebView?

Comment: Are you sure that whenever the app fails to login, `sharedCookies` has the right cookies ?

Comment: @ShalvaAvanashvili yes, the shared cookie storage acquires the correct session cookies before this view controller is presented